# Continuous updating of GUI plotting

Tags: matlab-guide

I am preparing a gui where the visibility of plots are controlled by checkbox selection in two different axes. Additionally, the user should select the Y vector from a popupmenu. The code is working fine (it could be more elegant) but I have issues with refreshing the plot automatically. At present, If I plot and subsequently select a different Y values from the popupmenu I have to uncheck and recheck the checkmark for the changes to take place in the plot. How can I make the GUI refresh the plot automatically if it is selected (checkmark). Any help is much appreciated:

Here is my code:

```
      % --- Executes on pushbutton1.
  function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  X=[1 2 3 4]
  Y1=[10 20 30 40]
  Y2=[-1 -2 -3 -4]
  handles.X=X;
  handles.Y1=Y1;
  handles.Y2=Y2;
  guidata(gcbo, handles);
  UnitFcn(handles)



  % --- checkbox function on/off
  function C = OnOffStr(D)
  OffOn = {'off', 'on'};
  L     = (D ~= 0) + 1;  % 0/FALSE => 1, anything else => 2
  if length(L) == 1
    C = OffOn{L};   % Reply a string
  else
    C = OffOn(L);   % Reply a cell string
  end



  function UnitFcn(handles)
  Y1=handles.Y1;

  for p = 1:numel(plotdata)

      Unit = get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');
      if (Unit==1)
      Y(:,p)=Y1(:,p);

      elseif (Unit==2)%
      Y(:,p)=Y1(:,p)*100;

      end         
  end

  handles.Y=Y;
  guidata(gcbo, handles);
  PlotFcn(handles)



  function PlotFcn(handles)
  X=handles.X;
  Y=handles.Y;
  Z=handles.Y2;

  %Plot in Axes 1
  set(handles.axes1, 'NextPlot', 'add');
      handles.plot1 = plot(X,Y,'visible','off','LineWidth',2, ...
                              'color', [0 0 0],'linestyle', '--', 'parent', handles.axes1);    

  %Plot in Axes 2
  set(handles.axes2, 'NextPlot', 'add');    
      handles.plot2 = plot(X,Y2,'visible','off','LineWidth',2, ...
                              'color', [0 0 0],'linestyle', '--', 'parent', handles.axes2);

  guidata(gcbo, handles);



  % --- Executes on button press in checkbox1.
  function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  set(handles.plot1, 'Visible', OnOffStr(get(hObject,'Value')));


  % --- Executes on button press in checkbox1.
  function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  set(handles.plot2, 'Visible', OnOffStr(get(hObject,'Value')));



  % --- Specify unit in popupmenu1.
  function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  UnitFcn(handles)

  function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
      set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
  end
```

This is a simplified code and the "for p = 1:numel(plotdata)" refer to a matrix where I have ~30 different plots.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it if I include this code in the PlotFcn:

```
for i=1:1:numel(X(1,:))
Checked(i,1) = get(handles.(sprintf('checkbox%d',i)),'value');
if (Checked(i,1)==1)
    set(handles.plot(i), 'Visible', 'on')
    set(handles.plot(i), 'Visible', 'on')
end
end
```

but I am not sure this is the best solution?? It takes some time to run 30 plots with this code.